# Nintex forms to Dyamics CRM

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, nintex-workflow

I've created a Nintex form to capture data on SharePoint, I would like to find out if it is possible to capture data from SharePoint using Nintex forms and populate the into Dynamic CRM entity?.

Thanks you.

Comment: Your question is very broad and not really suited for StackOverflow. Try sharepoint.stackexchange.com. Besides: You should always include more information what you have tried already. Nintex is a SharePoint Add-On, CRM is a totally different product family. You should look into SharePoint <-> CRM Syncing solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can capture data using Nintex Forms and push that into Dynamics. Since tou have forms, i hope you also have Nintex Workflow which has Dynamics CRM action available to use. This allows you to write to CRM without knowing much about the API structure. Some knowledge of CRM is needed to do this as it would be with anything.

You can create, update, query and more using the actions. It would pull either from the form or from the SharePoint list, starting the workflow and pushing that into CRM.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Nentex forms before but it doesn't look like they are able to submit directly to CRM. You have a couple options that I would look at in your case.

1. Use another web form if possible. An example of this is [PowerWebForm](http://www.powerobjects.com/powerpacks/powerwebform/)
2. If it submits to a sharepoint list perhaps you could use [Scribe](https://www.scribesoft.com) to sync the data into CRM.
3. Create a custom .net app that uses the Xrm Client library to push the data into CRM.